# Est-ce correct d'utiliser "pas de tel" suivi d'un singulier ?

Tags: prépositions

J'ai écrit une phrase en français et j'ai peur de faire un anglicisme, de l'anglais "such a [nom]" (c'est comme ça que j'ai pensé la phrase à la base).

La phrase ressemble à ça :

> [Décrit un type de fonction], mais notre programme ne possède pas **de telle fonction**.

J'ai beaucoup de mal à savoir si ma phrase est correcte ou non. Je trouve des exemples qui sonnent juste au pluriel ("*Je n'ai jamais tenu de tels propos*"), mais ici il est indispensable d'utiliser "fonction" au singulier.

Est-ce que *de* dans la phrase au pluriel provient de la négation (*je n'ai pas **de** fourchette*) ou du pluriel (***de*** *belles choses*) ?

Est-ce que ma phrase est correcte ? Est-ce que je devrais dire "*une telle fonction*" ?

Je précise que je décris un **type** de fonction, pas une fonction précise. Mon deuxième candidat serait :

> ...notre programme ne possède pas de fonction **de ce genre**.

(Ce n'est toujours pas vraiment ce que je veux dire, mais c'est le substitut le plus proche, si on ne compte pas "une telle fonction". De plus, j'apprécie les propositions mais je ma question porte plus sur la justesse de la phrase que j'ai proposé.)

Comment: « une telle fonction » est plus correct.

Comment: @Stéphane Mais je décris un type de fonction plus qu'une fonction, "une" me semble trop précis.

Comment: "une telle fonctionnalité", ça n'est pas mieux ?

Comment: @DavidBrabant En programmation ce sont pas des synonymes.

Comment: Tout simplement "cette fonction"

Comment: @sapienz C'est trop précis, je décris un type de fonction (différente selon chaque programme), pas une fonction exacte. Si j'utilisais "ce" je dirais plutôt "ce genre de fonction".

Comment: "une telle fonction" me semble être exactement ce que tu cherches, le "une" ne me semble pas préciser quoi quoi ce soit.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Oui, c'est aussi ce que je commence à penser. Il semble que *de* dans "*de tels propos*" est simplement le pluriel d'*un* ("*un tel discours*"), et ne vient pas de la négation.

Comment: Les deux phrases que vous citez sont suffisamment correctes. "Une telle" est peut-être marginalement meilleur.

Comment: Vous voulez dire "function" as in FP, Haskell, Scala... ou vous voulez-dire "fonctionnalité"?

Comment: @Frank Vraiment "fonction" comme dans un langage de programmation. Je l'aurais précisé sinon.

Comment: Visiblement vous décrivez les propriétés d'un programme. Si c'est le cas, vous avez l'option: "... entre autres fonctions, notre programme ne dispose pas de celle qui consiste à calculer ..."

Comment: Comme dit ci-dessus, vos deux phrases initiales sont tout à fait correctes, pas d'ambiguïté, suffisamment précis, tout le monde comprendra, pas besoin de chercher la petite bête :-)

Comment: ne possède pas ***de*** telle fonction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, I think art. + tel is a pretty natural French construction. :)

Here are the wordings that sound natural to me, in descending order:

> Notre programme ne possède pas une telle fonction.
>
> Notre programme ne possède pas de telle fonction.

With a preposition, the singular article seems to surface:

> Notre programme ne dispose pas d'une telle fonction.

In the plural, we see *de*, probably because *tel* is before the noun and hence forces *de* anyway:

> Notre programme ne possède pas de telles fonctions.

And of course there's the related construction, where *de* is unavoidable no matter what follows:

> Il n'y a pas de telle chèvre qui se téléporte.

*Edit to resolve confusion: This doesn't mean "There is no such thing as a goat that teleports" but "Such a teleporting goat (as you previously mentioned) does not exist."*

Here are an Ngram and some Linguee searches ([1](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=%22pas%20de%20tel%22)) ([2](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=%22pas%20un%20tel%22)) ([3](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=%22pas%20d%27un%20tel%22)) on it:

[image: Ngram]

Comment: Merci ! Content de voir que "*pas un tel*" existe bien :) J'aime aussi beaucoup "*ne dispose pas d'une telle fonction*". Si ma phrase dérange des natifs, je préfère l'éviter ^^

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr que ta dernière phrase soit correcte par contre. En plus de faire que le verbe "téléporter" est transitif, si tu veux dire "*there is no such thing as a teleporting goat*", ça ne se traduirait pas comme ça. Je pense justement que le but de "tel" est d'éviter les subordonnées : "Et une chèvre qui se téléporte ? / Restons sérieux, une telle chèvre n'existe pas". (c'est peut-être assez loin de ta phrase originale, corrige-moi si je me trompe)

Comment: I agree if the goal was to say: *"there is no such thing as a teleporting goat"*, it sounds wrong. It could sound right (maybe) if the meaning was something like: *"this kind of goat doesn't teleport"*, but other kinds of goat do.

Comment: La dernière phrase est correcte, mais le "telle" se rapporte à une spécification de ladite chèvre qui aurait été faite avant.

Comment: Not sure about the last sentence, it seems wrong but I really can't tell. As a native speaker I would recommend you to at least avoid using this formulation.

Comment: @AnneAunyme - je suis aussi natif, et je ne vois pas de problème avec cette phrase. Qu'est-ce qui vous embête dans cette phrase?

Comment: C'est une formulation que je n'ai jamais entendue. A la place de <<il n'existe pas de tel X qui Y>> j'entends plutôt <<Il n'existe pas de X qui Y>>, le "tel" me semble bancal dans la construction de la phrase. Ca ne veut pas dire que ce ne soit pas correct bien entendu.

Comment: J'ai interrogé ngrams avec "de tel * qui" et cette construction est apparemment utilisée.

Comment: J'ai pris un de ces ngrams au hasard: <<Ce sont de tels hommes qui m'adoptent>>, qui se divise en <<Ce sont (de tels hommes) qui m'adoptent>> là où la phrase de la chèvre est <<il n'existe pas de telle (chèvre qui se téléporte)>>. J'en ai regardé quelques autres et ils ont l'air d'être tous de ce genre.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53563/discussion-between-anne-aunyme-and-frank).

Answer (score 1):

Il y a deux problèmes différents ici. D'un côté, la grammaticalité de la phrase, *notre programme ne possède pas de telle fonction*, d'un autre, le sens visé dans le contexte : *notre programme ne possède pas cette fonction*

1. Pour le premier, on peut remplacer *fonction* par un nom à pluriel explicite :

   > Notre groupe ne possède pas de tels journaux/?tel journal.

   Le singulier semble étrange mais il y a une autre construction qui permet le singulier avec le sens d'exclure un élément parmi une liste

   > Notre programme ne possède pas telle fonction/telle et telle fonctions

   Le programme ne possède pas la fonction désignée extra-linguistiquement (p.ex. pointage)
2. Pour le second, on peut utiliser le pluriel (si il y a plusieurs fonctionnalités manquantes) ou recourir à une des alternatives avec un déterminant comme mentionné par [@LukeSawczak](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/24696/6517).

   > Notre programme ne possède pas
   >
   > - de telles fonctions
   > - une telle fonction
   > - cette fonction

Comment: NB. Il me semble que *posséder* et *fonction* marquent plus l'anglicisme que la construction en question. Peut-être que *disposer de* et *fonctionnalité* seraient plus naturels ?

Comment: *Posséder* est acceptable mais *disposer* ou *proposer* me semblent meilleurs. *Fonction* est établi en français quand il s'agit de nommer une procédure retournant une valeur dans beaucoup de langages de programmation et depuis plus longtemps en mathématiques et logique (http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fonction II.-A.-)